# Convert ISO 8601 date+time string to date

Tags: sirishortcuts

I would like to convert a date string from ISO 8601 format (as generated correctly by the "Format Date" block) back to a usable date. I have tried using "Get Dates from Input" but this unfortunately appears not to read the time part correctly.

The flow up to "Format date" yields the string `2018-09-24T11:33:23+02:00`, but the "Get Dates from Input" shows 12:00 as the time regardless of when this shortcut is run.

[image: Workflow showing problem]

PS: This is a simplified example. The actual date string will be coming from a web service, so I have no control over the incoming format - I need to parse this kind of date to continue with the other things I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that the parser works just fine if you replace the T in the ISO format with a space. It even appears to handle the time zone conversion correctly.

[image: Solution with replace text]